# Foreign key relationships with a condition

Tags: sql-server, constraints, relationship

Good morning,

I have a master table with an ID and a type. Depending of the type, i have children tables using this ID as a foreign key to ensure integrity.
Eg. for the master table:

```
master_ID, type
11, A
12, B
13, A
```

For the child table named Child_A, which stores additional data for type A ;

```
Child_A_ID, FK_master_ID, ....
1, 11, ....
2, 13, ....
```

How can I prevent the type in my master table to be changed to a different value when there is a corresponding record in my child table. My referential integrity is currently kept but it has no sense to store in the Child_A information of type A while, the record in the master table is of different type.

edit:

Would having a foreign key with the 2 attributes (ID and type) and repeating the type in each child tables be the only solution?
Eg. for the child_A table;

```
Child_A_ID, FK_master_ID, type, ....
1, 11, A, ....
2, 13, A, ....
```

Hope it's clear enough.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Are you trying to mean what if ID is changed in master table and there are still records in child table?

Comment: @murtazat No the ID in the master table will be kept and the integrity with the child tables will be maintained. It is the possibility to change the type attribute which causing me issues.

Comment: Even if you change data type of parent key in master table, I think referential integrity for child tables will be maintained by database.  Then, why do you worry about change in data type?  I am not sure about your requirements, but generally the concern will be about having orphan references in child tables.  Is there a specific necessity to maintain same data type in both parent and child tables?

Comment: You could probably use a [check constraint](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on your master table to prevent change in the type column if the master id exists in any of the child tables, but I'm don't think that it's a better way than using a multi-column foreign key.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes that's woulbd be a good option as i do not want to overload my children tables with a type attribute. Could anyone point me to a constraint example fitting my situation?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [check constraint](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) that uses a [user defined function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191007.aspx) to determine if the id value is contained in the relevant type table.

```
ALTER TABLE MasterTable
  ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_MasterTable_Type
  CHECK(dbo.fn_check_IdBelongsToType(master_ID, type) = 1)
```

and in the function itself you do something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_check_IdBelongsToType (
    @master_ID int, 
    @type char(1)
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
   IF @Type = 'A' AND EXISTS (
       SELECT 1
       FROM Child_A
       WHERE FK_master_ID = @master_ID 
   ) RETURN 1

   IF @Type = 'B' AND EXISTS (
       SELECT 1
       FROM Child_B
       WHERE FK_master_ID = @master_ID 
   ) RETURN 1

   IF @Type = 'C' AND EXISTS (
       SELECT 1
       FROM Child_C
       WHERE FK_master_ID = @master_ID 
   ) RETURN 1

   -- after testing all child tables, return 0 to indicate that the value was not found
   RETURN 0

END
```

Comment: (dbo.fn_check_IdBelongsToType(master_ID, type) = 0)
Probably must be equal to 1